# size and resizing browser window issue

Tags: html, css

Now, I have a website which is from my previous co-worker.
I get some issue about resizing the browser window.
In other words, I want my website to resize nicely when I resize the window, rather than having buttons, divs and all the rest to overlap and go crazy.

this is my website.

```
http://50.62.140.177/foxcode/index.html
```

What I would like to do is something similar to this say http://antobbo.webspace.virginmedia.com/photography/home.htm, you make the windows smaller and everything resizes ok.

Has that something to do with height/width/padding/margin using percentage instead?
I really don't know where to start from, so any hint or link to relevant resources would be great.

Comment: There's a topic known as Responsive Web Design that may be of interest to you.

Comment: See http://mashable.com/2013/03/18/web-design-tools/

Answer (score 0):

This is just as easy as setting the `html, body` to `auto` and add a `min-width` of `960px`

so something like:

In your header you put:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

And in your css you do:

```css
html {
   width: auto !important;
   min-width: 960px; // this depends on the width of your website, the example you provided is 960px
   /*rest of code*/
}
```

See all the `min-width` options [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width)

Hope that's it.

Comment: set width: 100%; and try it then.

Answer (score 0):

i can use chrome to check that.
open in chrome your website then click F12 for the debugger.
know in left down you got eyeglass click on it and then click where you want to change the size and in the right you can change it and see what append  change on your web source..

Answer (score 0):

Just add min-width: 768px; to both green divs. simple and quick

Answer (score 0):

Like other people said, min-heights and min-widths.

What I would also suggest is that you use a different technique for your full-screen background image. It seems to mess up when resizing.

Try using this;

```css
html{
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;  
  -webkit-background-size: cover; 
  -moz-background-size: cover; 
  -o-background-size: cover; 
  background-size: cover;  
}
```

It's the best practice for full-screen backgrounds. [More info from CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/).